# Click event in UIWebView doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

This is the script that I serve into a webpage:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
var style = myDiv.style;
style.opacity = 0;
style.zIndex = 10000;
style.position = 'absolute';
style.top = '0px';
style.left = '0px';
style.width = '100%';
style.height = '100%';
myDiv.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    new Image().src="http://myhostna.me/something.png?CLICKED"+Math.random(); 
});
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

When I serve this script in a webpage for a WebView on Android, I know that the click event fired because I can see the GET request for `something.png?CLICKED` in my access logs.

The problem is that I don't see those requests when I serve the script into a webpage for a UIWebView on iOS.

Does anyone know why that might be?

These webviews I'm getting served into are third party, and I don't know anything about what kinds of options they enable or disable.

Comment: Haha ajax hack it seems you made :-P

Comment: what about change it to new Image().src="http://myhostna.me/something.png?CLICKED"+Math.random(); Also add an alert('test'); to make sure it's being executed

Comment: I don't get it. Sorry, n00b here!

Comment: this comment area cut off my text. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
new Image().src="http://myhostna.me/something.png?CLICKED"
```

to

```
new Image().src="http://myhostna.me/something.png?CLICKED"+Math.random();
```

---

Edit:

please add these lines to your code:
(it can be after the line style.zIndex = 1000;)

```
style.width='500px';
style.height='500px';
style.background='red';
myDiv.innerHTML = 'my div';
```

and change

```
style.opacity = 0;
```

to

```
style.opacity = 1;
```

(it's easier to debug this way)

Also keep the alert('test'); inside the eventlistener function

You should see the alert box if everything is successfully executed.

---

It looks like the problem is your div does not have a size (unless you set it with CSS somewhere else)

---

new idea for debugging:

add this to the script

```
myDiv.id = 'myDiv';

document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id+' '+event.target.tagName);
}, false);
```

Then, when you click on your div tag, you should see 'myDiv DIV' in an alert box.
If you see other id (or empty string, since some page elements may not have an id attribute), that means you are not actually clicking on the div you are expecting. Then it could be a z-index related issue.

Comment: I see what you mean, now. That still didn't work. I uninstalled the app and re-installed it to make sure that I start with a clean slate, but I still don't see the requests even with the cachebuster.

Comment: How do you monitor the requests? Through a proxy? Also, can you add alert('test'); after the new Image()... line, then would you see the alert box when you click on iPhone?

Comment: I'm looking at my nginx access logs. The alert does not show up either.

Comment: OK. Can you try this: replace myDiv.addEventListener("click", function(event) with myDiv.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event)

Comment: Ok, that raises a different problem. I need the click event because I'm going to "save" it and dispatch it later. It needs to be a click because the UIWebView needs to know that the tap was UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked.

Comment: Then do you see the red div tag on the screen? Also, if you add alert(document.body); in the beginning of the script, it should show alert box but the value shouldn't be null or undefined, otherwise the last line of your script would cause an exception

Comment: So, this is strange, I guess. I see the red div, but I don't get an alert on iOS. It works on Android. Does iOS not recognize the "click" event?

Comment: iOS does recognize click event for sure. I think it could be a problem related to your environment (i.e., comflicts with the javascript libraries or css you are using on the page). I almost run out of ideas on what else the cause can be... One other way to debug it is to simplify the page and only leave a div tag with click handler, and see if it works

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me out! I will try to debug this further. :)

Comment: I just got a new idea (see above). It is one of useful debugging techniques I use sometimes on iOS/Android. If you want, you can have a try.